# Use of $ symbol in formulas

Tags: formula, workflow, validation-rule

can you please help me with my query:-

What is the use of **$ symbol**, especially in validation formula's please explain with example?

I have attached screenshot of validation rule where **$ symbol** is used before RecordType tag and profile name tag

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is used for [Global Variables](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&type=5). These are used in all kinds of formulas, including formula fields, validation rules, Process Builder, etc. They are used exactly as you would any other kind of variable, they just have special meaning in context (e.g. referencing the user's profile via `$Profile`).